# Is it be OK to ask for a specific publication?

Tags: discussion

As the question says would it be OK to ask this SE for a specific publication and if yes, what would be the criteria for permissibility?

Reasons for asking support:

- it is too old (pre-electronic) and only image copies are available
- Scholar and other search engines give the wrong citation
- only paid public access

Reasons for limiting questions

- invites for ask first, search later
- proliferation of paper requests
- risk of too many negative answers ('has been asked before', ' you can find it on Google', 'ask your library', etc)
- needs explicit e-mail exchange

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I think asking for papers is perfectly reasonable, however, although the academic publishing industry is completely broken, we still cannot break copyright laws. Each publication is different - [JASA, for example says](https://acousticalsociety.org/web-posting-guidelines/)

> authors have the right six or more months after publication to post
> copies of the article on institutional internet web sites or on
> governmental web sites, and have the right after publication to
> include the article on author‘s personal webpages.

which I think means it would be OK to post a link to a paper if someone requested it. Other organizations will obviously be different.

I would say questions should be closed with an explanation if they....

1. Ask for an open access paper (just lazy).
2. Ask for a paper which has already been asked for (i.e. duplicate).
3. Ask for a paper which cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0):

A question/answer could be added such as "What should I do when I don't find a paper" and people could be redirected to this question/answer (via a comment below their question). The issue is that even if they already ticked the "check list",  we wont be allowed to share it  as a response most of the time for copyright reasons as Jamie pointed out.

What about using the chat room to ask for papers (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137244/bioacoustics)? People would ask there, leave their email, and others can send them  a copy by email, then the asker writes to say he found it. However, this requires that people checks the chat room regularly, or configure a notification (by clicking on "enable desktop notification" on the right-hand side)

Comment: The chat room is an interesting idea! I was checking it regularly at the start but it hasn't been used in days. Perhaps if we did set up a "how do I find a paper" question, then that answer could suggest the chat room? I've got the alerts on and don't mind for now because its quiet :)